# When I try to open Wamp, it tells me: "This program can only be installed on versions of Windows designed for the following processor architectures

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, wamp

My computer is a Windows 7 32-bit operating system yet every time I try to open 32-bit WampServer download it keeps suggesting it can't be installed. I've also tried installing the 62-bit version yet it gives me the same exact message.

I was successfully able to install WampServer on my computer last year. I am trying to install it again, and it gives me the same message, over and over again.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: Error: This program can only be installed on versions of Windows designed for the following processor architectures: x64]

Comment: Can you give more information about the system you are running it on? Manufacturer(Make),Model,Processor ETC.

Comment: Dell computer and a windows 7 operating system. But I managed to resolve the problem (got my wamp successfully downloaded) but I'm curious to know why the latest wamp 32-bit version wouldn't download on my computer.

Answer (score 3):

It appears the installer you're using is for 64 bit Windows.  I would try downloading the 32 bit version again.  I'm not familiar with Wamp, but did a search and found [this page](https://bitnami.com/stack/wamp/installer) from bitnami with the current version 7.1.22-1.  The 32 bit download is the lower box:
[image]

If this installer gives you the x64 error again, there may be an error with the installer file on the website.  In this case, you can try using an older 32 bit version in the "Other versions" list.

Comment: I appreciate the help but I found a much easier way. I went directly to the wamp website and downloaded a older 32 bit version, wampserver 2.5 with 39.9 MB and made in 2014, I will include the link: https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%202/Wampserver%202.5/

Comment: I saw WampServer when I did the search, but was unsure which software you were referring to "Wamp" in your question. Was the download link "https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/files/WampServer%203/WampServer%203.0.0/" where you got the 
 Wampserver version 3, 32 bit (x86) installer that errored?